# Colour problem with Select component using sx prop Material ui v5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a dropdown on a grey blackground which has white text. However, the arrow next to the text still remains as default black. How do I make it so that the arrow is also white aswell? I couldn't find anything on which prop to pass in in the [docs](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/). Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

My code:

```
                  <Select
                    id="dropdown"
                    value={dropdownValue}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    disableUnderline
                    variant="standard"
                    sx={{ color:"#ffffff" }}
                  >

                    <MenuItem value="DROPDOWN">DROPDOWN</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value="Value2">Value 2</MenuItem>
                  </Select>
```

Comment: dropdown arrow is an `SVG`. but you can provide `dark` theme for the button. check this => https://codesandbox.io/s/2vq8w4nnjn?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

```
    <Select
                    id="dropdown"
                    value={dropdownValue}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    disableUnderline
                    variant="standard"
                    sx={{ color:"#ffffff" }}
inputProps={{style:{color:'red'}}}
                  >

                    <MenuItem value="DROPDOWN">DROPDOWN</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value="Value2">Value 2</MenuItem>
                  </Select>
```